# Editing Extension Using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I can’t figure out how to edit an extension on google chrome. I’m using selenium webdriver, google chrome, and windows. Whenever I load it in with my zip file, I need to change its settings.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension(“my extension”)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)`
```

How would I edit the extension?